# Writing formulas one below the other and source next to the formula

Tags: equations, citing, formulas

I have a problem. I want to write several formulas one below the other, I do this using `amsmath`. However, once I use that, the defined code that packs the source data for the formulas next to each other no longer works (see photo).

Is there an option to write the formulas one below the other and have the sources next to the formula number?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\eqcite{oom}{%
  \def\@eqcite{\org@cite}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}
    {\appto\@eqcite{[#1]}%
     \IfNoValueF{#2}
       {\appto\@eqcite{[#2]}}}%
  \appto\@eqcite{{#3}}}

\let\@eqcite\@empty
\def\@eqnnum{%
  {%
    \normalfont
    \normalcolor
    \ifx\@eqcite\@empty
    \else
      \@eqcite\space
    \fi
    (\theequation)%
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\equation{%
  \DeclareCommandCopy\org@cite\cite
  \DeclareCommandCopy\cite\eqcite
}
\DeclareCommandCopy\org@cite\cite
\makeatother

\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{Formel}{Formel}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}

\begin{document}
The famous inequality math relation:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:test}
  \text{\cite{sigfridsson}}
  y \neq x 
\end{equation}


New formula

\begin{equation}
  \text{\cite[235]{sigfridsson}}
  y \neq x 
\end{equation}


\begin{align}
    \label{eqn:eqlabel}
    \begin{split}
        f(x) &= x^2 ,
        \\
        g(x) &= \exp( x ) .
    \end{split}
\end{align}


\cref{eq:test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

What I want (Formulas in a formula one below the other)

[image]

Without `amsmath` it works

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\eqcite{oom}{%
  \def\@eqcite{\org@cite}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}
    {\appto\@eqcite{[#1]}%
     \IfNoValueF{#2}
       {\appto\@eqcite{[#2]}}}%
  \appto\@eqcite{{#3}}}

\let\@eqcite\@empty
\def\@eqnnum{%
  {%
    \normalfont
    \normalcolor
    \ifx\@eqcite\@empty
    \else
      \@eqcite\space
    \fi
    (\theequation)%
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\equation{%
  \DeclareCommandCopy\org@cite\cite
  \DeclareCommandCopy\cite\eqcite
}
\DeclareCommandCopy\org@cite\cite
\makeatother

\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{Formel}{Formel}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}

\begin{document}
The famous inequality math relation:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:test}
  \cite{sigfridsson}
  y \neq x 
\end{equation}


New formula

\begin{equation}
  \cite[235]{sigfridsson}
  y \neq x 
\end{equation}


%\begin{align}
%   \label{eqn:eqlabel}
%   \begin{split}
%       f(x) &= x^2 ,
%       \\
%       g(x) &= \exp( x ) .
%   \end{split}
%\end{align}



\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your `amsmath` example:

1. You have the `\cite` inside a `\text`. This means that the code is executed inside a group, and all the changes to `\@eqcite` are local and disappear at the end of `\text`. So I changed the code to make the assignments to `\@eqcite` global. This requires that `\@eqcite` will be reset to empty at the end of the `equation` environment. However, this can fail if `equation` is used recursively. Normally it isn't but theoretically an equation could maybe contain some textbox that contains another equation. Maybe a bit farfetched, but it can be solved by saving `\@eqcite` in a local variable before any assignments, and restoring it from this variable at the end of the environment. This is the solution I have taken.
2. In `amsmath` the equation number is (usually) not generated by `\@eqnnum`, so the `\@eqnnum` code will not help. Instead it is generated by `\tagform@\theequation`, so this should also be patched. I have patched `\tagform@`, but rather than rewriting it, I used `\pretocmd` fro the `etoolbox` package, which I find cleaner. There is one problem: `\tagform@` is also used to generate equation numbers for `\eqref`. So if you would refer to another equation with `\eqref` inside another equation that has a `\cite`, the reference would also contain the citation. To solve this I redefined `\eqref` using the original definition of `\tagform@`. I added such a ref in the example to show that it works.

I also added some code to setup your `\cite` mechanism inside the `align` environment. Basically this would require duplicating the code for `\g@addto@macro\equation` in `\g@addto@macro\align`. There are a lot of `align`-like environments, however, and rather that duplicating the code for all of them, it can be optimized. All of them start with `\start@align` and they end with `\endalign`. But `\start@align` is a bit peculiar: you can't add code to it at the end; then it will break. So I added the code to the beginning with `\pretocmd`.

If there are any other environments where you want to use this, it's most probably just a matter of using very similar code. Note however that `amsmath` is a bunch of spaghetti-like code, so it can be a challenge.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\save@eqcite}{}
\NewDocumentCommand\eqcite{oom}{%
  \gdef\@eqcite{\org@cite}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}
    {\gappto\@eqcite{[#1]}%
     \IfNoValueF{#2}
       {\gappto\@eqcite{[#2]}}}%
  \gappto\@eqcite{{#3}}}

\let\@eqcite\@empty
\def\@eqnnum{%
  {%
    \normalfont
    \normalcolor
    \ifx\@eqcite\@empty
    \else
      \@eqcite\space
    \fi
    (\theequation)%
  }%
}

\g@addto@macro\equation{%
  \let\save@eqcite\@eqcite
  \DeclareCommandCopy\org@cite\cite
  \DeclareCommandCopy\cite\eqcite
}
\g@addto@macro\endequation{%
  \global\let\@eqcite\save@eqcite
}

\ifdefined\tagform@
  \let\orig@tagform@\tagform@
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\orig@tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}

\def\tagform@#1{\ifx\@eqcite\@empty
    \else
      \hbox{\@eqcite\space}%
    \fi\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}

\pretocmd\start@align{%
  \let\save@eqcite\@eqcite
  \DeclareCommandCopy\org@cite\cite
  \DeclareCommandCopy\cite\eqcite
}{}{}
\g@addto@macro\endalign{%
  \global\let\@eqcite\save@eqcite
}
\fi

\DeclareCommandCopy\org@cite\cite
\makeatother

\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{Formel}{Formel}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}

\begin{document}
The famous inequality math relation:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:test}
  \text{\cite{sigfridsson}}
  y \neq x 
\end{equation}


New formula

\begin{equation}
  \text{\cite[235]{sigfridsson}}
  \text{As in equation~\eqref{eq:test}:~}
  y \neq x 
\end{equation}


\begin{align}
    \label{eqn:eqlabel}
    \begin{split}
      \text{\cite{sigfridsson}}
        f(x) &= x^2 ,
        \\
        g(x) &= \exp( x ) .
    \end{split}
\end{align}


\cref{eq:test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]